# Emacs key binding to run make

Tags: emacs

I am working on a C++ project and I want to bind the <kbd>F10</kbd> key in order for the tests to run. The tests are the default target of a Makefile. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Mastering Emacs Keybindings](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/)? `f10` is the key and you may need to write a function for the actual test.

Comment: @Jon Lin: nice tip, thanks, looks really good

Answer (score 4):

To literally do what you want:

> (local-set-key [(f10)] (lambda () (interactive)(compile "make")))

However, you can use keyboard macros solve general problems like this in future.  Or use `repeat-last-complex-command' to look at the Lisp form of your last action to use in your own definition.

Answer (score 0):

Bind f10 to the command `compile`.

Comment: compile-command is a variable. The function is called compile